# Is that possible send compiled JavaScript to evaluate in a context in call stacks with remote debugging protocol?

Tags: javascript

I think people run into this for many times. In the context of one of the call stacks in Chrome Devtools, one wants to write in CoffeeScript and evalutate the code. It's not yet possible so I have to compile and paste my code there.

So there might be an idea about sending compiled code via Chrome debugging protocol, and fortunately there's an API for that. But I'm not sure:

```
request: {
  "id": <number>,
  "method": "Runtime.evaluate",
  "params": {
    "expression": <string>,
    "objectGroup": <string>,
    "contextId": <Runtime.ExecutionContextId>,
    "returnByValue": <boolean>
  }
}
```

In that protocol there's a:

> ExecutionContextId: integer
>
> #### id ( ExecutionContextId )
>
> Unique id of the execution context. It can be used to specify in which execution context script evaluation should be performed.
>   ```

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/runtime#command-evaluate

It's not mentioned in the same page on how I can get the context it's stopping at. So I want to ask if there's a chance for us to make it?

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? What "compiled code" means? How to use Coffeescript from the console? How to compile injected Coffeescript on the fly? What the executioncontextid means?

Comment: @Bergi I have to say the biggest mistake is I mispelled "remote debugging protocol". I don't this is a common question since not all people writes CoffeeScript or write with remote debugging protocol.

Comment: As I said, `executioncontextid` is from remote debugging protocol, you may see it in that link. But it's not explained in detail. So I don't have a good anwser for you last question.

Comment: What I'm asking is, while we are debugging in Chrome in a break point, is is possible we send code to evaluate code there from outside rather than pasting code into console to run it?

Comment: Well, if you're connecting to the debugging api, then yes you can send code "from the outside" rather than through the console's connection.

Comment: How about the that `contextId` in the docs, do you have information on that thing?

Comment: No, I don't have any docs available. My guess would be that an *execution context* either refers to [the stackframe part](http://es5.github.io/#x10.3) or a [page environment](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#script-execution-environment) (less likely)